# Is there a way to find the index of a UICollectionView section?

Tags: iphone, swift, uicollectionview

Is there a way to find the index of a UICollectionView section?

My CollectionView is populated by arrays that are contained in a master array, and I need to select the appropriate one for the section.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let collectionCell: ChecklistCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChecklistCollectionViewCell

    let section = //I need the index of the current section here!

    let sectionArray = allCards[section]

    collectionCell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: sectionArray[indexPath.row])

    return collectionCell

}
```

Similar to how it is done here:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let sectionArray = allCards[section]
    return sectionArray.count

}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let section = allCards[indexPath.section]
```

Comment: You, sir, are a true bro.